# Displaying a Numbered Math Expression Without Creating a New Line

Tags: spacing, equations, line-breaking

I want to display a numbered math expression without creating a new line. Example:

```
\textbf{Claim}:
            \begin{equation}\label{fpreservesorder}
            m,n\in{}\mathbb{Z}\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,n<m\implies{}f(n)<f(m)
            \end{equation}
```

[image]

What is the proper way to eliminate the new line? If I use inline mode I lose the numbering. \align and \equation create the new line. \aligned and \multlined seem not to number the expressions.

Comment: Theoretically you could put it into a small minipage, but you would still waste all that vertical space. You could use inline math with `\quad\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)`.

Comment: unrelated but don't use `{}` as in `\in{}`  and `\wedge{}` they create empty math atoms that will in general mess up your spacing,

Comment: Appreciate that! I had no idea.

Comment: Putting an equation into a wrapfigure might be interesting.

Comment: Depending on the spacing you want, you could use `\medskip\textbf{Claim}:\vspace{-\baselineskip}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I've augmented this answer to address the OP's follow-up question, about how to allow the claim to be split -- more or less automatically, I think -- across two or more lines.)

You could render the material in inline math and place it, along with the word **Claim** and the equation number, in a `center` environment. The reason I suggest you embed the material in a `center` environment that it'll provide some vertical whitespace padding, which is probably what you want anyway. In the code below, this is achieved by placing the claim in the argument of a macro called `\Claim`.

If the claim is too long to fit on a single line, you could use a variant of `\Claim` -- called `\BoxClaim` in the code below -- that places the material in a `\parbox` (sorry for the LaTeX jargon) of width, say, `0.7\textwidth`. If you go this route, be sure not to overuse `\left` and `\right` since material in a `\left...\right` group cannot be line-broken. You may also need to supply suitably placed `\allowbreak` directives to nudge LaTeX toward placing line breaks in mathematically (as opposed to typographically) superior locations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\counterwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example

\newcommand\Claim[1]{\refstepcounter{equation}
   \begin{center}
      \textbf{\textup{Claim}}\hfill$\displaystyle #1$\hfill%
      \textnormal{(\theequation)}
   \end{center}}
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\parbox[t]{0.7\textwidth}{\raggedright $#1$}}
\newcommand\BoxClaim[1]{\Claim{\mybox{#1}}}

\newcommand\blurb{%  % supplied by the OP
   \exists m\,\bigl[(m\in A \enspace\lor\enspace m\in B) \enspace\wedge\enspace 
   \forall a\forall b\bigl((a\in A \enspace\wedge\enspace b\in B) 
   \allowbreak \implies a\leq m \enspace\wedge\enspace m\leq b \bigr)\bigr]}

\begin{document} 

\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{5}

\noindent
Some text \dots
\Claim{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\quad\wedge\quad n<m\implies f(n)<f(m)} \label{claim:mn}
A cross-reference to equation \eqref{claim:mn}.
\BoxClaim{\blurb}\label{claim:blurb}
A cross-reference to equation \eqref{claim:blurb}.

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address some of the OP's follow-up questions:

- `\refstepcounter{<somecounter>}` increments the counter named `somecounter` by `1`, in such a manner that if you were to add a `\label` directive, you could then cross-reference the object (here: an equation) via the standard `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.
- `\textup{(\theequation)}` prints the representation of the equation number (here: section prefix plus dot plus actual equation number), surrounded by parentheses, using the upright font shape. The `\textup` directive is there to ensure that the composite equation number is always printed upright even if occurs in an evironment (such as a theorem-like environment) that typesets its contents in italics by default.

---

*Second addendum*: Do please look into the capabilities of the [amsthm](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) and [ntheorem](https://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) packages. The following sample code merely scratches the surface of what these packages can do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}       % or: \usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim} % create a theorem-like environment called 'claim'
\begin{document}

\begin{claim} \label{claim:trivial}
We hold the following truth to be unalienable:
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{claim}
A cross-reference to Claim \ref{claim:trivial}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain the function of \refstepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)} ? I noticed that the spacing gets messed up when I omit it. Also, when the claim gets too long this has problems. Is there a way to break a long claim into multiple lines without generating another equation number?

Comment: @Gary - Please see the addendum I just posted, on the meaning of `\refstepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)}`. Please provide more information on the topic of "the claim gets too long".

Comment: Thanks for the addendum. I'll check it out. If the proposition/claim gets long like $\exists m\left((m\in A\enspace \lor \enspace m\in B)\enspace \wedge \enspace \forall a \forall b((a\in A \enspace \wedge \enspace b\in B)\implies a\leq m \enspace \wedge \enspace m\leq b )\right)$, then the "Claim" text shoots up a line and the equation number gets displaced down a line (or more). Basically I don't know how to break the proposition/claim into multiple lines while keeping the numbering  and "Claim" text intact.

Comment: @Gary - I've modified my answer to show how the solution may be augmented (with a new macro called `\BoxClaim`) to handle claims that are "long" -- say, wider than `0.7\textwidth`.

Comment: The screenshot looks beautiful! So many math books have propositions/claims like these but LaTeX has no built in support for them, shocking. Did your addendum go missing? I didn't have a chance to read it yet. I am surprised that you used \newcommand for \blurb. Is that something you recommend for longer expressions? My instinct is to put the expression directly into \BoxClaim{} in the main body.

Comment: @Gary - I've reinstated the addendum; I had accidentally deleted it when I rewrote parts of the answer. I put the long claim in a separate macro in an attempt to provide a separation of contents and the way they get typeset; maybe this educational effort wasn't sufficiently clear. I don't know why you think it's "shocking" that LaTeX doesn't provide "built in support" for your preferred way to display claims. I, for one, would definitely *not* display claims the way you like to display them. I'd much prefer to number the claim directly and to start the claim with text, not math.

Comment: Thanks for reinstating the addendum. Are you able/willing to link me to an example of typesetting a claim/proposition in the manner that you prefer? My point is that "numbered claim--->proof, repeat" is a standard way of presenting information in math books but I don't know how to do it except with the method that you have showed me.

Comment: Put another way, if there is some standard method for typesetting propositions in the form "Proposition X.Y   (text+math)" without a forced newline and without destroying the document structure when the (text+math) gets too wide, then I'll gladly use it.

Comment: @Gary - Please see the second addendum I posted.

Answer (score 4):

You could abuse `flalign` or do a hand-made job using some low-level tricks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{flalign}
&\textbf{Claim:} && m,n\in\mathbb{Z} \wedge n<m \implies f(n)<f(m) &
\label{fpreservesorder}
\end{flalign}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{equation*}\refstepcounter{equation}
\hspace{0pt}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\textbf{Claim:}}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}
m,n\in\mathbb{Z} \wedge n<m \implies f(n)<f(m)
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}
\makebox[0pt][r]{\eqref{fpreservesorder2}}
\label{fpreservesorder2}
\end{equation*}
Another equation to see that the numbering is good
\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Beware that in the second case the equation might overlap “Claim”, if too long. Also, `\label` is *mandatory* in this construct.

Of course, if you have several of these claims, it's better to define a new environment. I provide definitions for both methods, take your pick. This also supports `hyperref`; in case you don't use it, leave out the definition of `\eqrefstar` and change `\eqrefstar` into `eqref`. The `claim2` environment doesn't require a `\label` inside it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% for the first
\NewDocumentEnvironment{claim1}{b}
 {\begin{flalign}&\textbf{Claim:}&&#1&\end{flalign}}
 {}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{claim}
\newcommand{\eqrefstar}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref*{#1}}}}
\newenvironment{claim2}
 {%
  \begin{equation*}
  \refstepcounter{equation}
  \stepcounter{claim}
  \ltx@label{claim-\theclaim}
  \hspace{0pt}
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\textbf{Claim:}}
  \hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}
 }
 {%
  \hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\eqrefstar{claim-\theclaim}}
  \end{equation*}\ignorespacesafterend
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{claim1}
m,n\in\mathbb{Z} \wedge n<m \implies f(n)<f(m)
\label{fpreservesorder}
\end{claim1}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{claim2}
m,n\in\mathbb{Z} \wedge n<m \implies f(n)<f(m)
\label{fpreservesorder2}
\end{claim2}
Another equation to see that the numbering is good
\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}

\ref{fpreservesorder}

\ref{fpreservesorder2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Final suggestion: leave “Claim:” on a line by itself.

Comment: In what sense is the first method an abuse of flalign?

Comment: Also, it seems that breaking with \\ when the claim gets too long leads to another equation numbering on the following line. I do not want this.

Comment: @Gary I said it is a bad way to do such things… And you didn't specify you wanted line breaks, did you? Use the `flalign` method, with `\notag` in the first line.

Comment: I'm asking why it's bad/abuse. As for the line breaks: I am hoping to find a method that will work for a large variety of claims. Certainly many claims will take up more than a single line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `fleqn` environment, from `nccmath`, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
    \begin{align}\label{fpreservesorder}
    &\textbf{Claim:} & & m,n\in{}\mathbb{Z}\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,n<m\implies{}f(n)<f(m)
    \end{align}
    \end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As soon as I \usepackage{nccmath}, I get an error: ! LaTeX Error: Command \darray already defined.

Comment: @Gary: Strange … Maybe you're loading a package that's incompatible with `nccmath`?

Comment: mathtools, breqn, amssymb are the other packages I have loaded.

Comment: The only one I never used is breqn (because it is said it has some problems). The other two are quite standard.